# Create a custom dataset for a report

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am using Reporting Services (SSRS) to a small application I am doing. I would like to create a custom dataset that is the result of a join of two tables. I found an article where the guy did it, but I could not understand how:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SLReporting.aspx

I found also this MSDN page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160345.aspx
but I can't get to the "The Query page of the Dataset Properties dialog box opens."

How can I do that? Do I have to do a SP in the database?

Thanks,
Oscar

Comment: Hi, could someone tell me why my signature was edited? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Oscar,

On the codeProject link the article tells "How to Integrate Reporting Services with Silverlight and RIA Services".

But the msdn page tells "How to create a dataset in Visual Studio".

I think this will help you more: [msdn-Reporting Services Tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170246%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi, sorry, either I didn't understand your answer or you didn't understand my question. I want to be able to create my own query to define the report dataset, but I couldn't find this option...